# error with docker container with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jenkins, docker, dockerfile

I am unable to install postgresql on existing jenkins docker image,below are the list of steps i have followed:

Step 1 : Download the [jenkins](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/)  and specify the name for the volume to jenkins-home as described in the below article

http://www.catosplace.net/blog/2015/02/11/running-jenkins-in-docker-containers/

using the below command download the image and specify the volume

```
docker create -v /var/jenkins_home --name jenkins-home jenkins
```

Step 2 : Updated the dockerfile please see below
[Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/MasoodGit/b944b1d1e9f6ab68a1da) added postgresql installation commands from [postgresql_dockerfile](https://github.com/andreagrandi/postgresql-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile)

Step 3 : Build the docker image

```
docker build -t ci_jenkins_docker .
```

Step 4 : Now run the ci_jenkins_docker image

```
docker run -p 8085:8080 --volumes-from jenkins-home ci_jenkins_docker
```

## I get below error message after running the above command

touch : cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied.

Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions ?

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have updated the Dockerfile, and works now. The issue was related to permission. I had to add user root to some RUN commands ( instead of postgres user as earlier ) https://gist.github.com/MasoodGit/b944b1d1e9f6ab68a1da

Answer (score 0):

When you mount an external volume, that happens at run time, and the permissions of the mounted volume over-ride whatever is set earlier in the Dockerfile image. In order to make the jenkins_home directory writable, you will probably have to change the permissions in an entrypoint script.